# error msg "The response was received at http://myflask.loca.lt/ instead of https://myflask.loca.lt/?acs" by using onelogin and python3-saml

Tags: python, saml, onelogin

I am implemeting SP using python3-saml for onelogin IDP. However, i get error

```
The response was received at http://myflask.loca.lt/ instead of https://myflask.loca.lt/?acs
```

my saml/settings.json is given below

```
{
    "strict": true,
    "debug": true,
    "sp": {
        "entityId": "https://myflask.loca.lt/metadata/",
        "assertionConsumerService": {
            "url": "https://myflask.loca.lt/?acs",
            "binding": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
        },
        "singleLogoutService": {
            "url": "https://myflask.loca.lt/?sls",
            "binding": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
        },
        "NameIDFormat": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress",
        "x509cert": "",
        "privateKey": ""
    },
    "idp": {
        "entityId": "https://app.onelogin.com/saml/metadata/ac64b1cf-7962-4f1d-a76f-80dece77a8d1",
        "singleSignOnService": {
            "url": "https://cognostics-dev.onelogin.com/trust/saml2/http-post/sso/ac64b1cf-7962-4f1d-a76f-80dece77a8d1",
            "binding": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
        },
        "singleLogoutService": {
            "url": "https://cognostics-dev.onelogin.com/trust/saml2/http-redirect/slo/1645664",
            "binding": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
        },
        "x509cert": "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"
    }
}
```

I run my web application on localhost but use "localtunnel" utility to get a public url "https://myflask.loca.lt/"  for this. Why I am getting above error? how can it be fixed?

added saml request info as asked

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                    ID="ONELOGIN_5bec34ff09934c65e681b4d32174928ee110f161"
                    Version="2.0"
                    ProviderName="SP test"
                    IssueInstant="2022-01-19T05:31:58Z"
                    Destination="https://cognostics-dev.onelogin.com/trust/saml2/http-post/sso/ac64b1cf-7962-4f1d-a76f-80dece77a8d1"
                    ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                    AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://myflask.loca.lt/?acs"
                    >
    <saml:Issuer>https://myflask.loca.lt/metadata/</saml:Issuer>
    <samlp:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress"
                        AllowCreate="true"
                        />
    <samlp:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact">
        <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
    </samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

added saml response as asked

```
<samlp:Response xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                ID="pfx413bd5c8-e95e-cbbd-cdf7-1796daa0a0f5"
                Version="2.0"
                IssueInstant="2022-01-19T05:32:23Z"
                Destination="https://myflask.loca.lt/?acs"
                InResponseTo="ONELOGIN_5bec34ff09934c65e681b4d32174928ee110f161"
                >
    <saml:Issuer>https://app.onelogin.com/saml/metadata/ac64b1cf-7962-4f1d-a76f-80dece77a8d1</saml:Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
            <ds:Reference URI="#pfx413bd5c8-e95e-cbbd-cdf7-1796daa0a0f5">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                <ds:DigestValue>HT8pN7TU6YPYbznR+QcAtA9pzaY=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>NQe2rkzYfyfmvhUDvkvKetIrh8Irm</ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>MIID5TCCAs2gAwIBAgIUKKfNS</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
    <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
    </samlp:Status>
    <saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    Version="2.0"
                    ID="A36f1fa7d9d562a03193e5ac0660979e3c1042edf"
                    IssueInstant="2022-01-19T05:32:23Z"
                    >
        <saml:Issuer>https://app.onelogin.com/saml/metadata/ac64b1cf-7962-4f1d-a76f-80dece77a8d1</saml:Issuer>
        <saml:Subject>
            <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">shardul.kumar@cognostics.de</saml:NameID>
            <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2022-01-19T05:35:23Z"
                                              Recipient="https://myflask.loca.lt/?acs"
                                              InResponseTo="ONELOGIN_5bec34ff09934c65e681b4d32174928ee110f161"
                                              />
            </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml:Subject>
        <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2022-01-19T05:29:23Z"
                         NotOnOrAfter="2022-01-19T05:35:23Z"
                         >
            <saml:AudienceRestriction>
                <saml:Audience>https://myflask.loca.lt/metadata/</saml:Audience>
            </saml:AudienceRestriction>
        </saml:Conditions>
        <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2022-01-19T05:32:22Z"
                             SessionNotOnOrAfter="2022-01-20T05:32:23Z"
                             SessionIndex="_676ec47c-c9c8-449a-839d-a14c79fb1178"
                             >
            <saml:AuthnContext>
                <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
            </saml:AuthnContext>
        </saml:AuthnStatement>
    </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

Comment: These kinds of SAML2 questions really need more info such as the AuthnRequest.  I suspect that the problem is the way that you have your ssl setup.  Not really sure why you are using localtunnel utility (are you hosting your Service Provider local).

Simply configure your web server with SSL and update your hosts file to point to the ip of the web server with the name you are using above.  Normally looking at the AuthNRequest and the Response you can see where the values don't match

Comment: hi @TimothyLegge         I am running my web app on localhost so i need some public ip to connect with IDP hence I am using localtunnel utility for that.      I have added saml req and res xml in the main thread. can you please help to figure out what is wrong in that?     i have not done any ssl setup. i have just run the code which i have donwloaded from git.....can you please elaborate what is sl setup issue?

Comment: Unless you are doing something different than most, SAML does the authenticaton via   browser redirects.  You go to https://myflask.loca.lt which should be a web server configured for SSL/TLS (https) in port 443.  The SP (web application) redirects the browser to https://cognostics-dev.onelogin.com/trust/saml2/http-post/sso/ac64b1cf-7962-4f1d-a76f-80dece77a8d1 you login in and then it would redirect the browser back to https://myflask.loca.lt/?acs.  Everything in the browser - I would have to check onelogin but many SAML IdPs do not work without SSL